# Unsafe parameterized ArrayList cast after an instanceof check

Tags: java

Hi guys i got a problem with an unsafe cast operation.
Here is the problem. I gotta Constructor which accepts different types of Orders (PlayList, UserOperations, etc.) or should. So i decided to give it a Parameter as Object and check the type of the received once called. The Problem is one of those is a parameterized ArrayList (**ArrayList < PlayList >**) and since it is impossible to check a parameterized ArrayList I have to "dig" in. At first step i check if it is an ArrayList, at second I go into it an check the type of its content.
The problem afterwards is I get an unsafe cast warning which i dunno yet how to handle.

Greetings

```
    public Order(int aTyp, Object aOrderContent) {
    this.orderTyp = aTyp;
    if (aOrderContent instanceof ArrayList< ? >) {
        ArrayList<?> objList = (ArrayList< ? >)aOrderContent;
    if (objList.get(0) != null && (objList.get(0)) instanceof PlayList) {
        playList.addAll((ArrayList<PlayList>)aOrderContent) ;
    }        

    } else if (aOrderContent instanceof UserOP) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Rethink your design. Don't make the constructor take an `Object`. This is too opaque and allows consumers of your code to pass any type. It sounds like you should be [using a generic class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html) instead (though it's hard to tell based on your partial example). Possible solution:

```
// Might need an upper bound on T if you want to limit the allowed parameterizations
class Order<T> {

    private final int orderTyp;
    private final List<T> someList = new ArrayList<>();

    public Order(int aTyp, List<t> aOrderContent) {
        this.orderTyp = aTyp;
        someList.addAll(aOrderContent);
    }
}
```

Keep in mind it may be better to [use an `enum`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) instead of `int` for the `orderTyp`, if you know (at compile time) all the possible type values.

---

Side note: if a `List` is empty, [`List#get(0)` with throw an exception](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get%28int%29), not return `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making the constructor take an Object overload you constructor.  Have one take an `List<?>` and one take a `UserOP` ect.  Also, it would be ideal if all the options for the `List` extended from the same interface so you could have `List<MyInterface>` instead of `List<?>`